# changing inner div position to fixed is expanding more than the outer width

Tags: css, html, less

I am working on creating a fixed sliding sidebar for a Wordpress theme so I have to create a fixed positioned sidebar from [this tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/).

The present property of the outer division is relative. When I tried to change that to fixed it is changing the location of the sidebar. So I tried to create one more division just after the following division:

```
<div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar fourcol last clearfix" role="complementary">
```

with id sidebar-wrapper.

When I created the css property for sidebar-wrapper as `position:fixed;` it actually works but I see that its width is 489 pixels which is exceeding its outer div width 359 pixels. Since the outer div width is dynamic I can't create width attribute for inner div.

[Please find the code snippet here](http://jsbin.com/olaxav/1/edit).

The problem is because the fixed position div is trying to use all the available space of the browser instead of inheriting the parent div's width. When I tried declaring inherit it is changing to 419 pixels, I am confused how did it get that pixel count.

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used jQuery to calculate the width of the the sidebar and defined css property width of the fixed division dynamically using jQuery and it solved my problem.